# SQL Matching Rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am in trouble matching a value in other table and get the corresponding value. I have two tables, table one for product and table 2 for part, I need to match part no from second table with oe number of first table and get SKU.
The problem is OE Number is a bunch of numbers and i need to use something like instr. For Example the table look like this.

Product Table

```
 OeNum       |     SKU             
123-546-625  |     A001         
568-623-855  |     A002
```

Part Table

```
PArtid
 623
 625
```

for example I need to check if any row in OENUM have the string like part number and if there is one return the SKU. In above example partid 623 is in the second row of oenumber so it return value as

```
partID   |   SKU
  623    |   A002
  625    |   A001
```

i am using the query as :

```
select s.sku, p.id 
from sk s, part p 
where instr(s.oenum,p.id)>0;
```

but it doesn't seems to be working.

Please help.

Comment: `p.id` should be `p.partID`.

Comment: It works when I correct that typo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/522a73/2

Comment: So the oenum contains info about a product's all parts?

Comment: yes , we have same SKU for multiple parts and all the part with same SKU is stored as a single row in oenum.    Sorry , I have created a test table sk for Product with sku and oenum as fields and part table with field name as id for partid.

Comment: I showed in my fiddle that your query works if you use the correct column names. What problem are you having?

Comment: @ Barmar -  Yes, its working correctly. I think the problem is I have a large data sets in the original table and its  taking too much time to match the rows. Is there a faster way to do this faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **there are not** very much data in your tables I can offer you to try something like:

```
select s.sku, p.id from sk s join  part p on s.oenum like '%'+p.id+'%'
```

Comment: Why is this different from using `instr()`?

Comment: Actually instr is much better.

Comment: there are 200,000, rows in product table with oenum and sku and 293000 in the part table. I tried select s.sku, p.id 
from sk s, part p 
where instr(s.oenum,p.id)>0; and its been half hour and didn't get any rowsin result. :)

Comment: I think, if the Data is that big, so  you should use fulltext index and search for better result in this case match problem. @DeepakTiwari. I offered above query for few data.

Comment: I think as soon as you have to use functions in the where or on clause all queries will be really slow as the function has to be applied to all rows which will result in a complete table scan. Maybe consider splitting the OeNum in 3 columns with int type ?

Comment: @SaraMurtuzayeva I don't think full-text indexing will work for this. These aren't words, they're just parts of strings.